# nvarchar into integer conversion error

Tags: sql-server, casting, type-conversion, nested-function

I am trying to convert a column of zip codes into integers but I get a conversion error even when I casted the column correctly:

```
with zips as (
select  id ,cast(replace(replace(left(ltrim(Zip_Code),5), '-', ''), char(32), '0') as int) as zip_clean
from table1)

select * from zips 
    where zip_clean in 
    (19116,
    94595,
    60062)
```

Is there anything wrong with my nested cast function above?

Comment: it means your `replace` functions arent covering all possible scenarios in `Zip_Code`. Try with a `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ISNUMERIC(replace(replace(left(ltrim(Zip_Code),5), '-', ''), char(32), '0')) = 0`

Comment: it doesn't matter what the source is but I edited it. The question is if the nested functions are correct!

Comment: Agree with @B3S this query won't run as is. If I replace id and zip_code with string literals it does run. Something is off. And we don't have access to your data so if you have a zip_code with a character that is not a dash it could still fail. Also, do you mean to do the left after (outside) the replace?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data and desired result with `SQL Server` version you have.

Comment: Well, if you get a conversion error (which you stated you did) how would the nested functions be correct? That is rhetorical. Adding a `!` to your comment doesn't help you, it only hurts you.

Comment: @B3S isnumeric solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i think this answers to your question im going to move my comment here.

it means your `replace` functions arent covering all possible scenarios in Zip_Code. Try with a

```
 SELECT Zip_Code FROM TABLE1
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(replace(replace(left(ltrim(Zip_Code),5), '-', ''), char(32), 
    '0')) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your query is right but doesn't account for some invalid zip. I would try running the below which will return values that are not numeric. Then you may have to manually fix those or handle them some other way.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ISNUMERIC(replace(replace(left(ltrim(zip_code),5), '-', ''), char(32), '0')) = 0
```